# Strange PIN login on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

Got this strange PIN login on Windows 10 - does anyone know how to remove it?

It's on my Mum's PC - and she's `no idea` how it got there.

It's apparently nothing to do with Windows PIN login.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, you tried Settings - Accounts - PIN -> Remove and it doesn't disable this right?

Comment: Yup - As stated - isn't part of windows - there is no Pin to remove, only to add.

Comment: this might be a range things from a simple prank to ransomware. you should do a malware scan. also you should ask your mom how did she know the pin code if she has no idea how it got there because that info could help you.

Comment: She claims its something from "SkyGo" - A TV Provider in the UK - But I couldn't find any references to it.

Also, I don't suspect they would add that to a login..

Answer (score 2):

That is definitely a fishy PIN login. It's also not the PIN login that Windows would use, which looks like this

[image]

I would scan for viruses and ensure that there is no malware on the computer. That looks like something that would try to steal some information.

Comment: Yeh I thought the same! Strangely - typing 0000 (Apparently her pin) logins her in!?

Answer (score 2):

That PIN login  is coming from "HP SimplePass". It took me a while to remember the name and being able to get rid of it. If you're sure you really don't want it anymore, you can just uninstall it (that's what I did).

[image]

This is how the icon appears on the Uninstall Programs menu on the Control Panel

Comment: Good catch. This could be a "security" feature. Keylogging software can catch keystroke signals, but clicks on an on-screen keyboard would get around most simple/common keyloggers. Some security suites offer similar protections for banking websites where they'll provide an on-screen keyboard you click with your mouse.